# Pandas Column of Lists to Separate Rows

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I've got a dataframe that contains analysed news articles w/ each row referencing an article and columns w/ some information about that article (e.g. tone). 
One column of that df contains a list of FIPS country codes of the locations that were mentioned in that article.

I want to "extract" these country codes such that I get a dataframe in which each mentioned location has its own row, along with the other columns of the original row in which that location was referenced (there will be multiple rows with the same information, but different locations, as the same article may mention multiple locations).

I tried something like this, but iterrows() is notoriously slow, so is there any faster/more efficient way for me to do this? 
Thanks a lot.

- 'events' is the column that contains the locations
- 'event_cols' are the columns from the original df that I want to retain in the new df.
- 'df_events' is the new data frame

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
  for location in df.events.loc[i]:
    try:
        df_storage = pd.DataFrame(row[event_cols]).T
        df_storage['loc'] = location 
        df_events = df_events.append(df_storage)
    except ValueError as e:
        continue
```

Answer (score 1):

I would group the `DataFrame` with `groupby()`, explode the lists with a combination of `apply` and a `lambda` function, and then reset the index and drop the level column that is created to clean up the resulting `DataFrame`.

```
df_events = df.groupby(['event_col1', 'event_col2', 'event_col3'])['events']\
                 .apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.values[0]))\
                 .reset_index().drop('level_3', axis = 1)
```

In general, I always try to find a way to use `apply()` before most other methods, because it is often much faster than iterating over each row.

Comment: I have found a solution to my problem, switching to itertuples() made it magically fast:
   `data = []
    for row in df.itertuples():
        for location in row[14]: #defines the position of locations in the tuple
           data.append(row[0:13]+(location,))`

Comment: Did my solution not work? Please give it a shot - it might be more efficient and more compact.